# Como puedo enviar una imagen(o mas) desde C# a mi API REST y guardarlo en mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, api

Lo siguiente es mi codigo y me funciona para mandar datos desde C# a mi API REST y esta información se guarda correctamente en la base de datos:
asi mando la información desde C#:

```
using (var WC = new WebClient())
            {
                WC.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
                WC.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                var datajson = josnencode;
                var response = WC.UploadString("http://www.mipaginaweb.mx/RegClient",datajson);
                dynamic respuestatxt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
                string msjok = respuestatxt.mensaje;
                MessageBox.Show(msjok,"Cliente Registrado",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
```

Donde "josnencode" son mis datos serializados en formato json.

Datos recibidos desde C# en formato json en mi API

```
if($_GET['url'] == "RegClient")
        {
            $json_string = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $body = json_decode($json_string);
            $nombre=$body->nombre;
            $retorno = transaccion::InsertClient($nombre);
            if ($retorno) {
               echo json_encode(array('resultado' => 'OK','mensaje' => 'Cliente registrado exitosamente!'));
           } else {
                echo json_encode(array('resultado' => 'NONE','mensaje' => 'No se pudo registra el cliente'));

            }
```

transactios.php

```
public function InsertClient($nombre)
{
$query = $sql ->prepare("INSERT INTO MiTabla(Nombre) VALUES(?)");
        $query->bind_param('s',$nombre);
        $query->execute();
}
```

Ahora como puedo mandar una imagen(o varias) siguiendo la misma logica de lo que ya tengo? Tomando en cuenta que puedo insertar a la base de datos con lo que les muestro...

Gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando tu pregunta

> Como puedo mandar una imagen(o varias) siguiendo la misma lógica de lo que ya tengo? Tomando en cuenta que puedo insertar a la base de datos con lo que les muestro...

Aquí tienes varias acciones

1. Enviar imagen por [WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) (hay que convertirla a un array de byte)
2. ... entonces tambien debemos conocer como convertir una imagen a byte[] en c#
3. En la DB deberías guardar en MySQL al tipo de columna correcta, BLOB, medium blob, varbinary, etc

Vamos a ver entonces por partes

**Enviar imagen por WebClient**

Como ya sabrás [WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) Tiene varios metodos, entre los cuales podemos encontrar [UploadData](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata?view=netframework-4.7.2)   (y su correspondiente Async [UploadDataAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync?view=netframework-4.7.2))
Se puede ver en la firma del método que envía el parametro byte[] data

```
public void UploadDataAsync (Uri address, string method, byte[] data);
```

NOTA: También existe el metodo [UploadFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) que tendrias que darle la ruta del del archivo (y siempre hay cuestiones de permiso, , o si lo tienes en disco o en db, etc) pero también es una alternativa mas corta dependiendo de tu caso.

Por el tema 
**Convertir image en byte[]**

Te puede ayudar

- [How to convert image to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array)

Pero es básicamente

```
 public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
 {
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       imageIn.Save(ms,imageIn.RawFormat);
       return  ms.ToArray();
     }
 }
```

**En la DB deberías guardar en MySQL en la columna**

Aquí seria bueno que guardes en la DB en el formato adecuado (yo te puedo decir las opciones en MS SQL Server) aquí en MySQL seria bueno saber la versión o si necesitas mas ayuda al respecto

Creo que te puede servir

- [The BLOB and TEXT Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html)

Avísanos si quieres profundizar en algún tema en particular
Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Gran parte de tu comentario me ayudo a guiarme y  buscar información por el lado correcto, al final utilize lo que ya tenia junto con convertir la imagen a un array de byte, pondre la forma de como lo resolvi contestando mi pregunta yo mismo, saludos.

Comment: Que bien @Manny que te ayudo. Y es bueno si puedes compartir tu propuesta de solucion. Ademas te invito cuando puedas a que mires 
[HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) y la parte asíncronas de las peticiones